# Appending each element in a vector of strings to a repeating sequence of numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe that does not have sample names. I have a vector of these sample names, but the length is not equal to the rows in the dataframe. This is because the each sample has several "Peak" rows.

I want to append the first element of my sample name vector to each repeating sequence of numbers in "Peaks" starting with 1.

Here is what I have:

```
Sample_Names <- c("S1","S2","S3")

Data <- tibble(Peak = c(1:3,1:2,1:4),
                   Value = c(101:109))



Peak Value
 1    101       
 2    102       
 3    103       
 1    104       
 2    105       
 1    106       
 2    107       
 3    108       
 4    109
```

I want to add each element of my sample_names vector **in order**, for each repeating sequence of numbers to get this:

```
Sample Peak Value
S1     1    101     
S1     2    102     
S1     3    103     
S2     1    104     
S2     2    105     
S3     1    106     
S3     2    107     
S3     3    108     
S3     4    109
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Several of these solutions worked perfectly, thanks! Assigning the Sample_Name to every first number in the sequence, followed by filling is very straightforward. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

An option with `dplyr` would be to `rep`licate the 'Sample_Names' after getting the count of grouping elements with cumulative sum

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
    mutate(Sample =  rep(Sample_Names, tabulate(cumsum(Peak==1))))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#   Peak Value Sample
#  <int> <int> <chr> 
#1     1   101 S1    
#2     2   102 S1    
#3     3   103 S1    
#4     1   104 S2    
#5     2   105 S2    
#6     1   106 S3    
#7     2   107 S3    
#8     3   108 S3    
#9     4   109 S3
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[, Sample := rep(Sample_Names, tabulate(cumsum(Peak==1))) ]
```

Or another option is `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
setDT(Data)[Peak == 1, Sample := Sample_Names][, Sample := na.locf(Sample)][]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Data %>%
    group_by(Peak) %>%
    mutate(Sample = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(Sample = Sample_Names[cummax(Sample)])
```

In Base R, you could do

```
Sample_Names[cummax(ave(Data$Peak, Data$Peak, FUN = seq_along))]
```

Comment: You could use `rowid` from data.table` `Data %>% mutate(Sample = Sample_Names[cummax(rowid(Peak))])`

Answer (score 0):

We can create a counter which increments when `Peak == 1` using `cumsum` and use it to subset `Sample_Names`.

```
Data$Sample <- Sample_Names[cumsum(Data$Peak == 1)]

# A tibble: 9 x 3
#   Peak Value Sample
#  <int> <int> <chr> 
#1     1   101 S1    
#2     2   102 S1    
#3     3   103 S1    
#4     1   104 S2    
#5     2   105 S2    
#6     1   106 S3    
#7     2   107 S3    
#8     3   108 S3    
#9     4   109 S3
```

---

We can also use `tidyr::fill`

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  mutate(Sample = ifelse(Peak == 1, Sample_Names, NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(Sample)
```